# Error al insertar timestamp

Tags: java, sql-server

Tengo preparada la siguiente sentencia...

> Query para insertar TimeStamp

```
 public void insertarValores() throws SQLException{
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    conectar con = new conectar();
    Connection conn = null;
    conn = con. conectar();  
    try{
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(ldt.toLocalDate());
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);
        ps.setString(1, user_dto.getId_usuario());
        ps.setString(2, instdDto.getId_instituto());
        ps.setString(3, dto.getT1_A_A());
        .
        .
        .
        ps.setTimestamp(39, getCurrentTimeStamp());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println(""+e);
    }finally{
        cerrar(ps);
        cerrar(conn);

    }
} 


private static java.sql.Timestamp getCurrentTimeStamp() {

java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
return new java.sql.Timestamp(today.getTime());

}
```

Al ejecutar me aparece la siguiente SQLException:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: No se puede insertar un valor explícito en una columna de marca de tiempo. Utilice INSERT con una lista de columnas para excluir la columna de marca de tiempo o inserte DEFAULT en la columna de marca de tiempo.
```

Comment: Una consulta, en la estructura de la tabla, ese campo de fecha le tienes una restricción de "default value"?

Comment: Para todos los campos de la tabla tengo habilitado "Permitir valores Null".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisando la documentación de los campos timestamp, resulta que no puedes hacer cambios a los registros directamente, pues trabajan como un "rowversion". Si quieres usar un campo fecha utiliza `date` o `datetime`, de otro modo, en la estructura de la tabla define el `timestamp` con un `default`.

Referencia: [timestamp](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms182776(v=sql.90))